# Robust regression and singular error

Tags: regression, robust

I got this error message from a robust regression in r ;  "'x' is singular: singular fits are not implemented in 'rlm'"

I could solve it by removing some variables.

My question is ,  can i progrom r to  solve it on it's  own ? so i will not have to remove variables to solve it.

Comment: 'How to program it' is off topic here. FWIW, the "'x' is singular' means you have multicollinearity.

Comment: Simple solution: use the output of `lm` to find the variables it dropped.  Unless `rlm` is reweighting a relatively large number of observations to zero (which would be hard to do), this will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the same issue with `rlm()` when an x (predictor) variable is coded as a factor with empty levels (for example, `factor(c("a", "b"), levels=c("a","b", "c" ))`). Simply converting the factor to a character vector solved my issue. Alternatively, one can use `forcats::fct_drop()`.

Comment: I had this issue as well. Really hard to find the cause, though I knew it had to do with that factor variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check for NA values, multicollinearity and duplicate observations. [multicollinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multicollinearity) For duplicate observations use jitter rnorm() as suggested: [Cause of singularity in matrix for quantile regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78022/cause-of-singularity-in-matrix-for-quantile-regression).