# Quantile regression for panel data - what is a tolerable zero tolerance in `rqpd`?

Tags: r, quantile-regression

I'm using the R package [rqpd](https://rdrr.io/rforge/rqpd/man/rqpd.html) to perform quantile regression on panel data with penalized fixed effects and running into singularity issues. The issue can be "fixed" by simply decreasing the `ztol` parameter which determines when numerically small numbers should be considered to be zero. When I decrease the value from its default `1e-5` to `1e-10` everything checks out, but this feels a bit arbitrary. So my question is what sort of values for `ztol` are adequate? Is there a way to judge that say `1e-9` is still appropriate but `1e-10` is taking things a little to far?

I'm conscious that another possible [cause of singularity in quantile regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78022/cause-of-singularity-in-matrix-for-quantile-regression) is binned data, but my dependent variable is only binned across the entire panel, not for individual groups for which fixed effects are introduced (see chart). Judging from the [source code](https://rdrr.io/rforge/rqpd/src/R/rqpd.R) of `rqpd()` it looks like the test for singularity is run across the whole panel, so I tried jittering the dependent variable anyway, but with `ztol=1e-5` and reasonable jitter factors there was still singularity.

Any help/views would be much appreciated - thanks!

[image]

Comment: As an aside, inefficiency of quantile regression and lack of ability to model a variety of correlation patterns in longitudinal data may be cause for considering semiparametric models.  See [this](https://fharrell.com/post/re).

Answer (score 1):

I have since reached out to Roger Koenker and received a prompt response. The answer is twofold where the first part reflects Koenker's response: 1) singularity of $X'X$ may be due to multicollinearity, in which case decreasing `ztol` may lead to convergence, but does not tackle the problem of linear dependencies in and of itself; 2) if 1) is not a reason for concern, then decreasing `ztol` should not be problematic though as per [Koenker (2004)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X04001113) estimation will become more computationally expensive since the number of non-zero elements increases.