# Quantile regression visualization and evaluation

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, prediction-interval, quantile-regression

I'm trying to perform quantile regression in R on a multivariate data set, where I want to visualize the 10% and 90% bounds. I also intend to calculate PICP - Prediction interval coverage probability according to

[image]

Where

[image]

LPI<sub>i</sub> and UPI<sub>i</sub> are respectively lower and upper bounds of the prediction interval constructed for ith sample. t<sub>i</sub> is the ith target value. I make predictions with another model - in the example I use a linear model, but my intention is also to include other models such as a GP.

Currently, I'm a bit stuck on the visualization part, as I'm not sure how to visualize the lines for the upper and lower bound, when I have multiple covariates.

I've tried to create a reproducible example below which highlights what I want to do. I'm using the `quantreg` package:

```
# Create a covariate
set.seed(123456)
x1 <- rnorm(1000, mean = 75, sd = 5)

# Create a dummy encoding for the hours of the day and remove first column to avoid dummy trap.
dummies <- sample(1:24, 1000, replace = TRUE)
dummies <- model.matrix(~factor(dummies))[,-1]
colnames(dummies) <- paste0("hour", seq(2:24))

#Create a response variable
set.seed(123456)
y <- rnorm(1000, mean = 50 + x1 + dummies %*% (10 * 1:23), sd = 10)

# Combine into a data frame
df <- cbind.data.frame(y, x1, dummies)

# Split into some train and test data
set.seed(123456)
id <- sample(1000, 900) # 90-10 ratio
train <- df[id, ]
test <- df[-id,]

# Load Quantile Regression package
library(quantreg)

# Fit Quantile model for tau = 0.1 & tau = 0.9
QR_fit_1 <- rq(y ~., data = train, tau = 0.1)
QR_fit_9 <- rq(y ~., data = train, tau = 0.9)

#### Results in: Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Singular design matrix
#### Add small jitter according to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78022/cause-of-singularity-in-matrix-for-quantile-regression
jittered_y <- jitter(df[, 1])
train_jit <- train
test_jit <- test
train_jit$y <- jittered_y[id]
test_jit$y <- jittered_y[-id]
# Fit Quantile models again - still issues
QR_fit_1 <- rq(y ~., data = train_jit, tau = 0.1)
QR_fit_9 <- rq(y ~., data = test_jit, tau = 0.9)

# From the documentation, I try the suggested approach of changing method on page 5
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/vignettes/rq.pdf
QR_fit_1 <- rq(y ~., data = train, tau = 0.1, method ="fn")
QR_fit_9 <- rq(y ~., data = train, tau = 0.9, method ="fn")

# Visualize y with the upper & lower quantiles
plot(c(train$y), xlim = c(0, 1000))
points(QR_fit_1$fitted.values, col=2)
points(QR_fit_9$fitted.values, col=4)
abline(QR_fit_1, col=2)
abline(QR_fit_9, col=4)
axis(1, xlim = c(0, 1100))

# Make predictions with another model, i.e linear model
fit_mod <- lm(y ~., data = train)
y_pred <- predict(fit_mod, test)

# Add predicted data points to graph
test_fit_1 <- predict(QR_fit_1, test)
test_fit_9 <- predict(QR_fit_9, test)
points(c(901:1000), y_pred, col = 3)

## Compute PICP 
???
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this would be greatly appreciated. As the ??? indicates, I'm a bit unsure of how to calculate the PICP, as I'm not sure how to obtain the lower and upper bounds.

Comment: When you include covariates, you make the problem inherently multidimensional and not conducive to easy visualization. If you just wanted to do a plot of the mean instead of the quantiles, what would you do? (“I don’t know,” is an acceptable answer.)

Comment: I don't know =)